# Vue.js Uncaught Error in browser when prop object throws an error

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I have a component Login.vue that has a UserService prop.
UserService is implemented by FirebaseUserService.

My problem is when I click on the button signIn with invalid inputs, it makes the method signIn in FirebaseUserService throw an error (desired behavior).

When the error comes to Login.vue component, the code into the catch is executed (desired behavior). But I have an error in the console of my browser that says *Uncaught error: Error message* (unwanted behavior).

I wonder why I have this uncaught error even though I have a catch block that is executed in Login.vue signin.

P.S. I tried with a method that throws in the Login.vue component and i don't have an uncaught error

**Login.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="login">
    <b-row align-v="center" align-h="center">
      <b-col cols="12" sm="8" md="4">
        <b-card
          border-variant="primary"
          header="Login"
          header-text-variant="white"
          header-bg-variant="primary"
          align="center"
        >
          <b-form-input class="my-1" v-model="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"></b-form-input>
          <b-form-input class="my-1" v-model="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></b-form-input>
          <b-button
            @click="signIn(email, password)"
            variant="primary"
            type="button"
            id="signInButton"
            class="my-1"
          >Login</b-button>
          <p class="text-danger" id="errorMessage" v-bind:value="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</p>
        </b-card>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { UserService } from '../domain/user/UserService'

@Component
export default class Login extends Vue {
  @Prop() private userService!: UserService;
  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  errorMessage: string = '';

  async signIn(email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.userService.signIn(email, password)
      this.$router.push('/profile')
    } catch (error) {
      this.errorMessage = error.message
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**UserService.ts**

```
export interface UserService {
  signIn: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
}
```

**FirebaseUserService.ts**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import Auth = firebase.auth.Auth

export class FirebaseUserService implements UserService {
  private readonly WRONG_PASSWORD_CODE: string = 'auth/wrong-password'
  private readonly WRONG_EMAIL_CODE: string = 'auth/user-not-found'
  private readonly INVALID_EMAIL_CODE: string = 'auth/invalid-email'
  private readonly USER_DISABLED_CODE: string = 'auth/user-disabled'

  private auth: Auth

  constructor(auth: Auth) {
    this.auth = auth
  }

  public async signIn(email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch((error:any) => {
      if (error.code === this.WRONG_EMAIL_CODE) {
        throw new Error('Invalid Credential')
      }
      if (error.code === this.WRONG_PASSWORD_CODE) {
        throw new Error('Invalid Credential')
      }
      if (error.code === this.INVALID_EMAIL_CODE) {
        throw new Error('Invalid Email')
      }
      if (error.code === this.USER_DISABLED_CODE) {
        throw new Error('User disabled')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

[image: Uncaught error browser]

Comment: Instead of using `.catch(err => {...})`, surround the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` call with `try-catch`, and throw the new error inside the `catch` block. Also be sure to have a default case that throws an error to avoid unintentionally swallowing the original error.

Comment: @tony19 I did that at first, but there is an issue with fitebase auth at the moment that makes the try catch block working incorrectly. See: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1881

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the call with a `Promise`, as suggested in a [comment of that issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1881#issuecomment-510189685)?

Comment: @tony19 Oh! Yes, it works! :) It is ugly, but I think this is the only solution for the moment :) Thank you.